# Cppcheck says 'Reference to temporary returned' but code runs fine. False positive maybe?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Consider the following mwe, implementing a simple class that overloads the multiply operator:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  double a;
  
  A &operator*(double b)
  {
        a *= b;
        return *this;
  }
    
  friend A &operator*(double b, A &m) { return m * b; } // (*)
};

int main()
{
    
    A a;
    a.a = 5.0;
    a * 3.0;
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    3.0 * a;
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs just fine, printing the expected output. However cppcheck gives the following warning.

```
tmp.cpp:15:48: error: Reference to temporary returned. [returnTempReference]
friend A &operator*(double b, A &m) { return m * b; }
```

When rewriting `(*)` as

```
friend A &operator*(double b, A &m) { m * b; return m; }
```

The error from cppcheck disappears.

So, is this an actual problem and I'm overseeing something, or is it a false positive by cppcheck?

Some context: In my code, class `A` is actually a Matrix class, for which I don't want to create a new object upon multiplying with a constant, thus returning the reference.

Comment: `friend A &operator*(double b, A &m) { return m * b; }` is undefined. You are returning a reference to a temporary. "runs fine" is a possible outcome of undefined behavior

Comment: Crashes on my machine.  That's the fun part of undefined behavior:  crashing is okay, runs fine is okay, emailing your browser history to your grandmother then formatting your hard drive is okay.

Comment: `operator*` should not return a reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Why is it a reference to temporary? Shouldn't it be ultimately returning `m` that was an argument?

Comment: [Canonical implementations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) for operator overloading.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: How is that a temporary? It's just `{ return m.operator*(b); }`. That operator in turn returns `*this`, i.e. `m`. How could there be a temporary? It would have to bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you are right. I was confused by unconventional use of `*` where it should be `*=`

Comment: @MSalters it isnt. I already realized it. I will leave the comment for reference and hope someone will write a less confused answer

Comment: I guess cppcheck always expects that `m * b` is an rvalue-expression; it won't check how `operator*` is implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does not return a reference to a temporary. One is inclided to think that, because what you implemented as `operator*` is actually an `operator*=`. If you did implment `operator*` which does not modify the current `A` but returns a new one, then returning a reference would be problematic.

I dont have the tool available, but I would expect it to not complain about:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  double a;
  
  A &operator*=(double b)
  {
        a *= b;
        return *this;
  }
    
  friend A &operator*=(double b, A &m) { return m *= b; } // (*)
};

int main()
{
    
    A a;
    a.a = 5.0;
    a *= 3.0;
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    3.0 *= a;
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which really does the same as your code, but with the expected semantics of `*=`.

As songyuanyao mentions in a comment, it might be that the tool simply expects `m*b` to be a rvalue-expression, as it usually is, without actually checking the implementation of your `*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I purposely did not implement `operator*=` because I want to chain multiple multiplications in one line, for which I need `operator*` I guess. But for this simplified scenario your adjustment using `operator*=` works fine.

Comment: @SimhonH thats a misunderstanding you can chain `*=` just like you can `*`.

Comment: How would chaining `*=` look like? When changing `a *= 3.0;` into `a *= 3.0 * a;` using your rewritten code, the compiler yields an error, complaining that `operator*` is not defined for arguments of type double and A.

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. I honestly didn't know that one can chain `*=` and I'm definitely not a fan of the look of it.

Comment: You'd need to override the precedence: `(a *= 3.0) *= a;` or use a sequence of statements: `a *= 3.0; a *= a;`.

Comment: @SimonH the thing is that `a * b * c` is expected to not modify any of its operands by most coders used to idiomatic c++. Your `operator*` breaks the principle of least surprise. Others using your `*` will very likely write broken code and then wonder why. `operator*=` on the other hand is expected to do exactly what you implemented

Comment: @SiinmH btw if you interested in the issue of avoiding the temproies in something like `a = a * a + 3.0;` then you might be interested in expression templates. Thats how algebra libraries approach this. In a nutshell, it is about returning a proxy object from `operator*` and delay the actual computation until the result is actually needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Wow nice, expression templates actually exactly look like what I wanted when I wrote my matrix code. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

It is a false positive on cppcheck side, but also your code is highly confusing to any readers (as shown in comments) because you don't obey [basic rules and idioms for operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading). It may or not be related to cppcheck mistake.

Proper implementation of binary `operator *` should return a copy:

```
class A {
public:
  double a;
  // no need for friend declarations, your data member is public
};

A operator*(A a, double b)
{
    A.a *= b;
    return a;
}

A operator* (double b, A a)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Comment: Hm yeah I see. But when chaining multiple multiplications together, each creating a new really big temporary matrix, this idiomatic approach loses its attraction imo. I guess I should've put this information in the question, too.

Comment: @SimonH Then implement `*=` operator which modifies it's argument directly (see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76999896/7976805)). Although I'd be strongly opposed to implementing `operator *= (double, A)`, that's very unidiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a misleading warning. I wouldn't call it a "false positive", because this sort of code does warrant a warning, but a different warning.

Specifically, the member `operator*` should be `const`, and return a temporary by value. This overload of `operator*` is clearly supposed to be a product (in mathematical sense) considering it commutes.

I understand the idea of multiplying with a constant, and not creating a temporary. You can express that as `Matrix operator*(Matrix&& lhs, float rhs)`. The rvalue reference makes explicit that `lhs` is altered.